# How do I find context lines before *and* after a match using grep?

Tags: linux, grep, command-line-arguments

I need to find out and output 10 lines before pattern and 20 lines after it at once.
What am I doing wrong? I don't get the proper result.

```
grep -B 10 "next" file1.txt | grep -A 20 "next" file1.txt
```

Comment: Try `grep -B 10 -A 20`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I need to find out and output 10 lines before pattern and 20 lines after it at once.

You won't get the right result with a pipeline because you won't have the right context lines after piping the output. Instead, put all your context requirements into the same set of command-line arguments. For example:

```
grep -B 10 -A 20 "next" file1.txt
```